# How does Linux Kernel assigns memory pointers when a process uses shm_open()?

Tags: c, linux, ipc, shared-memory, interprocess

I'm on Linux 2.6 and I have a weird problem. I have 3 concurrent processes (forked from the same process) which need to obtain 3 DIFFERENT shared memory segments, one for each process. Each of the process executes this code (please note that 'message' type is user-defined)

```
    message *m;
    int fd = shm_open("message", O_CREAT|O_RDWR, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
    ftruncate(fd, sizeof(message));
    m = mmap(NULL, sizeof(message), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    char messagename[16];
    snprintf(messagename, sizeof(messagename), "%p", m);
    char path[32] = "/dev/shm/";
    strcat(path, messagename);
    rename("/dev/shm/message", path);
```

Let me explain a bit: I want every process to allocate a shared memory zone which contains a message. To make sure another process (the message receiver) can access the same shm, I then rename my shm file from "message" to a string named after the message pointer (this because the process which receives the message already knows the pointer).

When executing the program, though, I tried to print (for debugging purpose) the pointers that every process received when mmapping the fd obtained with shm_open, and I noticed that all of them got the SAME pointer. How is it possible? I thought that maybe other processes did the shm_open() after the first one did and before it renamed the segment, so I also tried to make these lines of code an atomic operation by using a process shared mutex, but the problem persists.

I would really appreciate any kind of help or suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your processes all started with identical address space layouts at the moment of forking, and then followed very similar code paths. It is therefore not surprising that they all end up with the same value of `m`.

However, once they became separate processes, their address spaces became independent, so having the same *value* of `m` does not imply that all of the `m`s are pointing to the same thing.

Furthermore, I am not sure that your idea of renaming the `/dev/shm` entry after creating the shared memory block is safe or portable. If you want each process's shared memory block to have a unique name, why not base the name on the process ID (which is guaranteed to be unique at a given point in time) and pass it directly to shm_open, rather than going to the bother of renaming it afterwards?

Comment: Thanks, your idea of using pid seems good and I surely will give it a shot. However, through shm_open() I ask a shared (and not private) memory pointer and I was expecting a different pointer everytime, regardless of the virtual memory space of the process which, I was thinking, is not relevant when it comes to shared memory.

Furthermore, even if I use a different name for each of the shm_open() called by the processes, they all get the same address. If shm_open() + mmap() gives a shared memory pointer, how can they all be the same if the name of the shm is different?

Comment: ALL access to memory from a process goes through that process's virtual address space. The underlying memory may be shared, but each application's view of it is private. So it may be appear at the same address in each process, or different addresses in different processes, entirely at the discretion of the OS.

Comment: ... or conversely, different shared memory blocks may appear at the same address in different processes, which is what's happening to you.

Answer (score 1):

The same virtual address in different processes can (and usually does) map to different physical pages in memory. You might want to read [the wikipedia article on virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

Comment: Thanks! I already know about virtual memory. I was thinking, though, that even if the processes have different memory spaces, using shm_open() and mmap() would return pointers to some shared zones which should be "unique" every time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem simply by making the mmap before forking. So after forking the same area is shared between all processes. I then put my semaphores and mutexes on defined positions. It works perfectly.